# Any Asp.Net 4.7.2 Examples of Api Resource Using IdentityServer4 as Authority?

Tags: identityserver4

Just looking for an example project of a full framework (4.7.2) API that's being protected with access_token (bearer token) using IdentityServer4 as the authority. Seems like that would be pretty common but I can't seem to find one.

BTW - not talking about running IdentityServer in 4.7.2, or a 4.7.2 web site, just a plain old MVC Api project that runs in 4.7.2 that will be protected by an access_token that comes from IdentityServer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So all you need is to validate an access_token?
Use [IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3.Contrib.AccessTokenValidation/) -- a fork from the original IdentityServer3, refactored according to the recent framework.